# Code snippet formatting don't work after bulleted list formatted line

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow, code-formatting, markdown

I have problem when answering or asking questions on StackOverflow

Suppose I have two possible code snippets and I want to ask which is better.

Here is code 1:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// my code here
    }
```

and here is code 2:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // my code here     
    }
```

You may notice that ***I can put the code in code snippet block***
But this is not possible if I add Bulleted list just before this code snippet,
Like this:

- Here is code 1

  @Override
              protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // my code here
              }
- Here is code 2

  @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // my code here
      }

Now, no matter what I try ***I cannot format my code in code snippet form***, even without the short cut **ctrl + k**.

You can even check and try to edit this question attempting to put the code in code snippet.

Moreover if I have say 30 line of code, the ctrl + K destroys the formatting of code instead of putting in code snippet.

It literally means that **if have bulleted list as your first statement in your question/answer you cannot add code snippet**.

So,

- Is this a known bug?
- Is there any alternative to put code in code snippet. If yes, then how?

Comment: Oh, whoops. Bad vote, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

- This is the first bullet

  ```
  Then your code here
  ```
- Then your second list item

  ```
  Then more code here
  ```

You need to indent by eight spaces, not four, to get code blocks inside bulleted lists.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but isn't that suppose to happen by default, i.e. after I select the code part and do ctrl + k..

Comment: @CRUSADER That one's [meta-tag:status-bydesign], since you don't always want that kind of formatting. It's a little weird, though. Might want to submit a feature request, but be sure to be clear about what you're asking for

Comment: how more clear can I get than this, and this occurred to me when I was answering a question on stackoverflow. What I know that ctrl + k means a code snippet format, it has to function that way. Thanks for answering so quick.

Comment: If you'd like to, feel free to post a feature request!

Comment: How can I post a feature request, please guide me..

Comment: oh, do you mean adding feature-request tag in question above??

Comment: Yeah, but I think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for guiding...

Comment: Wouldn't have guessed that ;)